# Is there a delay for StartObservingDevicePresence?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use StartObservingDevicePresence to receive BLE advertising that could be send several days after calling StartObservingDevicePresence.
After few hours, it's not working anymore on Android 13. The only solution I have is StopObservingDevicePresence then StartObservingDevicePresence. I don't want to keep my app in background.

How can I do?

Thank you